# Permissions for a stored procedure with bulk insert

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I want to create a stored procedure to perform a bulk insert so a user I grant access to the stored procedure can run it without any other permissions.

Is there any way I can grant "ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS" to the stored procedure so I don't have to grant server wide bulk op permissions to the user?

Is there any other solution?

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the stored procedure to use ["EXECUTE AS"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) to have it run under a different context.

Comment: It would be good, except there is a bug in SQL that prevents this from working for bulk inserts.  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125602/the-rights-for-administer-bulk-operations-are-checked-at-the-wrong-tmie

Comment: More detail for anyone else trying to do this, EXECUTE AS works fine in SQL Server 2008, but only if you "ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON", otherwise you'll just get a generic permissions error.